# How to resume to a page which is not a MainPage.xaml with the live tile

Tags: windows-phone

I am using a windows phone SDK 8 and my app is for windows phone 8 only, I have created a Flip live tile template on the Hub and have successfully achieved app resume to the other page with the non live tile , but when I press the live tile it returns to the Main Page which is not what I want, I want it to resume to the current page from which the application was suspended.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821027.aspx

Read this page it will help you a lot.